# Evaluation of a function in other functions with same parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Consider the toy example below:

```
someNum :: Int
someNum = 42

funcCommon :: Int -> Int
funcCommon x = x + 1

func1 :: Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
func1 x f = f x

func2 :: Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
func2 x f = f x

f1 = func1 someNum funcCommon 
f2 = func2 someNum funcCommon 

main = do
  print f1
  print f2
```

The same arguments **funcCommon** and **someNum** get applied as a parameters to both func1 and func2 so we get a situation where func1 and func2 are declared separately (are different functions) but both end up calling the same function with the same argument. How many times then does **funcCommon someNum** get actually evaluated? Does the result get reused and there is only one evaluation of **funcCommon someNum**?

Comment: In theory, it only needs to be evaluated once. In practice, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: By default Haskell has no *tabulation*, so it will usually end up evaluate the function twice. Although it is possible that it can get optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language does, strictly speaking, not define whether it's evaluated once, twice, or 37 times, or what it even means to evaluate something a particular number of times. All it does guarantee is that the strictness rules are obeyed, i.e. with

```
f1, f2 :: [Int]
f1 = repeat 1
f2 = error "evil"

main = do
  print f1
  print f2
```

you could be sure that the error isn't triggered because printing `f1` will actually just forever spit out `1` digits and thus `f2` is evaluated exactly zero times.

For some particular situations, the compiler could actually do all the computations for `f1` and `f2` at compile-time and neither of them would be “evaluated” at runtime at all.

**In practice, you should expect two evaluations to happen**. Confirming that two functions do the same thing is a hard problem, so the compiler generally won't bother.

Comment: In OP's case f1 and f2 are not only doing the same thing, they are doing the same thing the same way. It is trivial for the compiler to merge identically implemented functions. GHC does this. Of course in this particular case they are simple enough to be completely inlined in main too.

Comment: @n.m. _does_ GHC merge them? Sure, eliminating _identically implemented_ functions is trivial, but it also seems patently useless for non-trivial code. If anything, I'd say it would make sense to use this for triggering a warning. Interesting would be to eliminate stuff that's merely equivalent, but that really isn't feasible.

Comment: I think it just happens in a CSE pass.